# ggplot polar_coord space out text better

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have some data in the data frame `times.posix`. Since it's time data,  I want to visualize it as a circular histogram. My code is this:

```
ggplot(times.posix) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = pct.hour(dropoff.posix) ), bins = 24, color = 'black', fill = 'blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23, labels = paste( (11:(11+11) )%%12 + 1, c(rep('AM',12), rep('PM', 12) ) ) ) +
  ggtitle('Dropoff time frequency') +
  coord_polar()
```

and my graph ends up like this

[image]

The actual geom_hist ends up fine but the text around it is weirdly spaced - the labels seem alright starting at 12AM but by 11PM theyre a full block behind. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force "12 PM" to equal "12 AM" by explicitly truncating the values: replace `x = pct.hour(dropoff.posix)` by `x = floor(pct.hour(dropoff.posix))`.

Here are data simulated *via* `times.posix <- data.frame(Time = 24 * rbeta(1e3, 1.4, 1.1))` rendered with your code (naming the truncated values `Time`):

[image: Figure]